# Is there a language-independent way to add a function to JSR223 scripting bindings?

Tags: java, function, scripting, jsr223

The [JSR223 `Bindings` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/script/Bindings.html) allows you to expose arbitrary Java objects to scripting languages. But they have to be objects. I would like to define a function `quit()` that can be called from the scripting environment that turns into `quitObject.run()` in Java. But JSR223 doesn't define the concept of a function object. Is there a language-independent way to do the following in Javascript, namely to take a Runnable() and create a function in the scripting environment?

```
 static private Object asFunction(ScriptEngine engine, Runnable r) 
    throws ScriptException
 { 
        final Bindings bindings = engine.createBindings();
        bindings.put("r", r);
        return engine.eval(
          "(function (r) { var f = function() { r.run(); }; return f;})(r)",
          bindings);
 }

 Runnable quitObject = /* get/create a Runnable here */
 Bindings bindings = engine.createBindings();
 bindings.put("quit", asFunction(engine, quitObject));
```

With the builtin Javascript support for JSR223 this creates a `sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.InterpretedFunction` which does what I want. But it obviously won't work in Jython or whatever, and I'd like to make this language-independent.

I don't want my script users to have to type `quitObject.run()` as that's clumsy, and I don't want to parse script input to find `quit()` as it could be buried within other code.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [javascript engine source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/com/sun/script/javascript/RhinoScriptEngine.java#RhinoScriptEngine) you'll find how oracle/sun implemented 2 functions (print, and println) which are magically (or not so magically) present when you fire up your engine.

Those function are 'scripted' , which is more or less what you did.

What I would do is : load and evaluate a `bootstrap.[language_extension]` before evaluating any other input in the new context.

You could easily create such scripts for each language you intend to support.

Comment: interesting -- not what I had in mind but I'll have to check it out! thanks!